# How to Chain Rails ActiveJobs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq

I am looking for a way to be able run [Active Job](https://github.com/rails/rails/tree/master/activejob) serially. Ideally, a long running Job 1 is scheduled to run at a certain time. A similarly running Job 2 is slated to run only after Job 1 completes. Job 3 then waits for Job 2 to run to completion before it starts and so on.

I have to admit that I am rather new to background jobs in Rails but I am already using Active Job with Sidekiq as the job runner for simple fire-and-forget tasks.
I like Active Job because it provides a simple enough interface to dive almost immediately into background jobs processing. I can use Sidekiq without having to define workers, for example.

For reference, I have achieved something similar but it was on [.NET](https://www.microsoft.com/net/) using the excellent [Hangfire](https://www.hangfire.io/) library which has [continuations](http://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/quick-start.html#continuations) where you pass the ID of a parent job ensuring that the job will run only after the parent job has successfully completed.

It would be nice to have something as clean and simple as that using Sidekiq and Active Job but really any alternative ways to achieve the same thing are welcome. It doesn't have to be Sidekiq and Active Job.

Answer (score 2):

The most straightforward way to to this is to call a third job from within a second job, and the second one from within a first job